# What is shortest way to rename files in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have following files with names like:

```
Selection_Test_from_120118_1140118.txt
Selection_Test_from_monthly_120118_1140118.txt
```

how we can rename both files by removing string from file:

```
string1 --> Selection_Test.txt (remove "_from_120118_1140118")
string2 --> Selection_Test.txt (remove "_from_monthly_120118_1140118")
```

I want to use parameter expansion method instead of traditional cut command here

Comment: to remove the *longest, trailing* string matching `_from*`: `"${string2%%_from*}"`

Answer (score 1):

With Perl's standalone `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's/_from_[^.]*//' *.txt
```

If everything looks okay, remove `-n`.